# Python: Mechanize select_form returns nothing

Tags: python, mechanize

When trying to use the [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) i seem to be unable to use select_form(id) to retrieve the form even though there is an object generator in forms().

code:

```
import mechanize

urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/']

for url in urls:
    print url
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Firefox')]
    br.open(url)

    for form in br.forms():
        print form
    print br.select_form(nr=0)
```

output:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
<GET http://stackoverflow.com/search application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(q=)>>
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually *selects the form*, since it does not return any errors.

The reason you see `None` printed is that `select_form()` returns you `None`.

---

As a separate note, why don't use [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) instead of browsing with `mechanize`?

Comment: ah thanks that confused the hell out of me. Used stackoverflow only for this example, actually browsing completely separate websites.

Comment: I was so confused about this too. It would make a lot of sense that `select_form()` does also return the form it selects.